# VBA Userform (with activex date control) Memory Issues

Tags: vba, excel, memory-leaks, activex, userform

I created a date selector thats been giving me problems. The date selector is a userform with a couple activex controls called "LDdate" which is basically a pop up calendar for the user to select a date. I have a command button on the sheet that calls .show on the userform. The only code that I wrote for the userform is as followed:

```
Private Sub okbutton_Click()
    Sheets("Generate").Range("B2") = firstDate.Date
    Sheets("Generate").Range("D2") = lastDate.Date
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Everything seemed to work fine but now in two workbooks that have used it when going to save the excel file I first get the error message: System Error &h80004005 (-2147467259) and I click ok and it pops up about 3 more times. Then I get an error message saying: Excel cannot complete this task with available resources. Choose less data or close other applications. When I was trying to figure this out I also got out of memory errors randomly pop up.

My thought is that every time the user opens up the date selector userform an instance of the userform is created and then when the user clicks ok the command "unload me" is not actually killing the instance so there is a bunch running in the background.

I am 99% sure it is the date selection userform as when I removed it from the project my issue went away. [This picture shows the userform. The date drop down selectors are activex "LDate"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/055G7.png)

Comment: You shouldn't need to `Unload` anything. How are you invoking `.Show` on the form?

Comment: nameOfUserform.show  ..... I dont actually create an instance of the userform I guess which is why I unload it.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help! So it is likely that those errors I was getting was because I wasn't instantiating an instance of the userform?

Comment: Can't tell for sure. I do know that using the default instance and making the form run the show is the ultimate source of *lots* of headaches. Possible that the error has nothing to do with it, too. Putting an entire column in the clipboard can do that. Running Excel 32 or 64-bit?

Comment: 32 bit, I am a summer student at a large company writing macro's with no one to go to for help. I am a little nervous I will be running into issue's like this often...

Comment: Are you doing copy-pasting on the worksheet by any chance? I've seen this error before, when copying large data sets. Possible that the code itself has little to do with it. Try opening the file manually, then immediately saving. If you get the error, close Excel, verify that the EXCEL.EXE process is correctly shut down in task manager, then reopen it and try again - if no error, try the macro.

Comment: There is a little bit of copying and pasting but not entire rows or columns, just 20x20 ranges at most. Everything seemed to be working fine until I added in this date selector.